# Input number's value to append div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/enRy3c

Here's what I'm trying to do.

Say my input number is 5. I want to dynamically append 5 divs to the class `.enfants`. However I haven't figured out how to do that. I been searching and searching and I haven't came across anything.

**jQuery/JavaScript**:

```
var counter = 1;

// Value number = .enfants children
$(".ajouter-enfants").on('keyup change', function() {
  var yourChildren = "<div>" + counter++ + "</div>";
  var CallAppend = function() {
    $(".enfants").append( yourChildren );
  };
  
  // If 0 or empty clear container
  if ( $.inArray($(this).val(), ["0", "", " "]) > -1 ) {
    $(".enfants").html("");
    // If only add/have 1 div in container
  } else if ($(this).val() === "1") {
    $(".enfants").html("").append( yourChildren );
    // If > 0 add as many divs as value says
  } else {
    $(".enfants").html("");
    CallAppend();
  }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="contenu" align="center">
  <div>
    Value number = .enfants children
  </div>
  <input type="number" min="0" class="ajouter-enfants" value="0" />
  <div class="enfants">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A loop would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple loop?  If you just want to append, try something like this:

```
$(".ajouter-enfants").on('change', function() {
  var numDivs = $(this).val();
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i <= numDivs; i += 1) {
    $('.enfants').append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to *replace* instead of *append* the newly-created `<div>`'s, try something like:

```
$(".ajouter-enfants").on('keyup change', function() {
  var content = '';
  var numDivs = $(this).val();
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i <= numDivs; i += 1) {
    content += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
  }

  $('.enfants').html(content);
});
```

This will replace the entire content of any elements using the class `ajouter-enfants` with the number of `<div>`'s specified in the input box.

Comment: would $(this).val()'s return have to be parsed into a Number?

Comment: This is the rendered result - http://liveweave.com/5KNjtU  How would you get it to only append the value amount? It appends more when the value is (2 becomes 3, 3 becomes 6, 4 becomes 10 and repeats even when I'm decreasing the numeric value)

Comment: Depends on how it's used in the real-world.. is the content/value of the input box controlled?  If not then probably, yeah... but I leave that up to the OP

Comment: You asked for "append", not "replace".  If you want to replace the content with the number of div's specified, try http://liveweave.com/1EwIvX

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".ajouter-enfants").on('keyup change', function() {
    var num = +$.trim($(this).val()), target = $(".enfants"), i = 0, s = '';

    target.empty();
    if (!isNaN(num) && num > 0) {
        for (; i < num; i++) {
            s += '<div>' + (i + 1) + '</div>';
        }
        target.html(s);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you get it to only append the value amount? It appends more when the value is (2 becomes 3, 3 becomes 6, 4 becomes 10 and repeats even when I'm decreasing the numeric value) –
@Michael Schwartz

Here is another code example that might be helpfull.

```js
$(".ajouter-enfants").on('change', function() {
  var numDivs = $(this).val();
  var i;
  var html ='';
  for (i = 1; i <= numDivs; i += 1) {
  html += '<div>' + i + '</div>';       
  }
   $('.enfants').empty().append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenu" align="center">
  <div>
    Value number = .enfants children
  </div>
  <input type="number" min="0" class="ajouter-enfants" value="0" />
  <div class="enfants">

  </div>
</div>
```